# Running protoc commands not generating Register method

Tags: go, grpc

I am trying to generate service with plugin methods in for grpc go

This is my score.proto file

```
syntax="proto3";
option go_package="./livescore";

service ScoreService{
  rpc ListMatches(ListMatchesRequest) returns (ListMatchesResponse);
}

message ListMatchesRequest{
  string country=1;
}


message MatchScoreResponse{
  string score =1;
  bool live=2;
}
message ListMatchesResponse{
  repeated MatchScoreResponse scores=1;

}
```

When I am running this command

```
protoc -I=. --go_out=. score.proto
```

its working fine

But following command to generate `RegisterScoreServiceServer` as well

```
protoc -I=. --go-grpc_out=. score.proto
```

is giving me error

```
protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
```

I know the plugins flag is deprecated ,but then how to generate plugins as well .Its bit confusing any help would be welcome

Comment: Have you installed `protoc-gen-go-grpc` and added it to your path as per [the documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites)?. Try running it from the command prompt (e.g. `protoc-gen-go-grpc -help`) - if this fails then it is not installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [docs](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites) closely it mentions two things to be installed

```
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1
```

For second command you need `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1`

to be installed too.

For more look here

https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc#section-readme